# LAPACK giving me incorrect eigenvalues

Tags: matrix, fortran, lapack, eigenvalue

I am using DSYEV and DSYEVD from the LAPACK library to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors (Compilation syntax: gfortran  -llapack ). However, I find wrong eigenvalues (`-0.44,0.35,0.88`) for a particular matrix. What's going wrong?

One can easily see the matrix has zero determinant, so at least one eigenvalue must be zero.

Here is my code (hope it's not too big):

```
    Program Real_Eigenvec
    implicit none

    integer, parameter:: n=3
    integer:: i,j, flag
    real*8:: A(n,n),X(n,n) 
    real*8:: lambda(n)
    real*8, parameter:: p=0.5d0/dsqrt(2.d0), q=1.d0-1.d0/dsqrt(2.d0)


    Print*,'Enter flag: 0 for DSYEV, 1 for DSYEVD'
    Read*, flag


    A= transpose(reshape((/ 0.d0, 1.d0, 0.d0, p, q, p, 0.5d0, 0.0d0, 0.5d0 /), shape(A)))


    print*,'Dimension of the matrix, n=',int(sqrt(float(size(A))))

    Print*,'A matrix in full form:'
    Do i=1,n
      print 100, (A(i,j),j=1,n)
    End Do

    call Eigen(A,lambda,X,n,flag)

    !    Print the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

    PRINT 200
    DO i  = 1, n
      PRINT 201, lambda(i), (X(i,j), j=1,n)
    END DO

100 FORMAT (1X,10(:2X,F10.2))
200 FORMAT (/1X, 'Eigenvalue', 16X, 'Eigenvector^T')
201 FORMAT (1X, F10.2,4X,6(:f10.2))

    End Program Real_Eigenvec



!!!      SUBROUTINES -----------------------------------------


    Subroutine Eigen(A,lambda,X,n,flag)
    implicit none

    integer:: i,n,flag
    real*8:: A(n,n),Ap(n,n),X(n,n)
    real*8:: lambda(n)
    real*8, allocatable  :: work(:)
        integer, allocatable :: iwork(:)
    integer:: lwork,liwork,info

    print*,'n in Eiegen routine=',n

    lwork=3*n-1      ! DSYEV for flag=0
    if (flag==1) then ! DSYEVD for flag=1
      lwork=1+6*n+2*n**2
    end if 

    liwork=3+5*n


    allocate(work(lwork))
    allocate(iwork(liwork))

    Ap=A

    if (flag==0) then
      CALL DSYEV ('v', 'l', n, Ap, n, lambda, work, lwork, info)
    else
      CALL  DSYEVD ('V', 'U', n, Ap, n, lambda, work, &
                &   lwork, iwork, liwork, info)
      ! For doumentation visit: http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d1/da2/dsyevd_8f.html
    end if

    X=Ap

    print*,'info=',info

    deallocate(work)
    deallocate(iwork)

    End Subroutine Eigen
```

Comment: Not many people follow [tag:fortran90], if you want someone to help you, it is better to use [tag:fortran] and the version tag in addition only if necessary (which is not the case here).

Comment: Thanks @VladimirF. I will keep that in my mind for future posts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated in lapack [documentation](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dd/d4c/dsyev_8f.html) the `DSYEV` can be used for symmetric matrices.

> DSYEV computes all eigenvalues and, optionally, eigenvectors of a real **symmetric** matrix A.

In the example the matrix `A` is not symmetric

```
Dimension of the matrix, n=           3
A matrix in full form:
     0.00        1.00        0.00
     0.35        0.29        0.35
     0.50        0.00        0.50
```

In this case you should use `DGEEV` which is used for unsymmetric [matrices](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d9/d28/dgeev_8f.html)

> DGEEV computes for an N-by-N real nonsymmetric matrix A, the eigenvalues and, optionally, the left and/or right eigenvectors.

In general use the eigenvalues are complex numbers so you have to provide `WR` and `WL`. Also, you need to define whether you want left `VL` or right `VR` eigenvectors.

```
A * v(j) = lambda(j) * v(j)
u(j)**H * A = lambda(j) * u(j)**H
```

The definition of the function is:

```
DGEEV(JOBVL, JOBVR, N, A, LDA, WR, WI, VL, LDVL, VR, LDVR, WORK, LWORK, INFO)
```

I suggest to use it like

```
LWORK = 4*N
CALL DGEEV( 'N', 'V', n, A, n, wr, wl, Ap, n, Ap, n, work, lwork, info )
```

In order to get both left and right eigen vectors use

```
real*8:: A(n,n),VL(n,n),VR(n,n)
real*8:: wr(n),wl(n)
lwork = 4*N
allocate(work(lwork))
CALL DGEEV( 'V', 'V', n, A, n, wr, wl, VL, n, VR, n, work, lwork, info )
```

For your matrix the imaginary part of all eigenvalues is zero. So the eigenvalues are `(1.00, -0.21, 0.00)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was totally out of my mind that DSYEV only works for symmetric matrices. However, using `CALL DGEEV( 'N', 'V', n, A, n, wr, wl, Ap, n, Ap, n, work, lwork, info )` I'm still getting an error message:
`** On entry to DGEEV , parameter number 13 had an illegal value
 info=         -13`. I have declared `real*8:: wr(n), wi(n)`.

Comment: The message tells you to check argument number 13. Did you do that? Which one is that and which value it has?

Comment: Since you need eigenvectors @hbaromega you have to set LWORK >= 4*N. I will update it in the answer to

Comment: Sorry to say that `lwork=4*n` (i.e. 12 in my example) yields all eigenvalues to be zero ! @ctheo, are you testing my code as well?

Comment: Yes I did. The imaginary part of all eigenvalues is zero (wl), while wr is as above. What is the result (wr,wl) you get?

Comment: Sorry I mistakenly printed `lambda` instead of `wr` which is the argument of `DGEEV`. Once corrected, it gives me the expected eigenvalues and right eigenvectors. What would I have done to get the left eigenvectors or both?
I mean, do I need to call separately for left and right ones?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75592/discussion-between-hbaromega-and-ctheo).